# Detecting Mouse wheel in canvas

Tags: html, canvas

How to detect Mouse wheel movement in canvas I tried using:

canvas.addEventListener("mousewheel",startStroke,false);

But it isn't working.. 
What should i do..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Add a `tabindex` to your `canvas` element, this will make it receive the events:

```
 <canvas width="500" height="500" tabindex="2"></canvas>
```